# How to access usercontrol method from Class app_code

Tags: asp.net

I have one usercontrol on asp page

```
<%@ Register Src="UserControls/Show.ascx" TagName="ucShow" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
```

In that I have one method `Show()`.

I want to access this method from my class file. i.e  `class1.cs` which in `app_code`

How can I access this method from class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a user control on page called uc1 then you can use uc1.show() provided it is a public method.

If you want to access it in class1.cs file, you can do something like:

```
function doSomething(ref UserControlType ctl) {
//do some work
ctl.show();
}
```

from your aspx.cs you can call method like `doSomething(uc1);`

Comment: I dont want to access it from codebehind, but want to access it from app_code class.